# Player swift crash app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, player-swift

I have add Player-swift in my project to play video but when i pop that controller app getting crash with following log

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   'Cannot remove an observer  for the key
>   path "rate" from  because it is not
>   registered as an observer.'

any one have any idea? i have used this player https://github.com/piemonte/Player

Thanks in advance !

Comment: are you removed the `rate` observer in viewdisappear

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no i have not changed anything

Comment: check once your code ,

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to unsubsribe from observing some property. For example if you subscribed for observing `rate` then to remove observing use

```
player.removeObserver(observer, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayer.rate))
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**: check [KVO basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html).
**Second**: in objective-C you would the removing observers code into try-catch block and live happy. The apple's guide tell the same:

> Asking to be removed as an observer if not already registered as one
>   results in an NSRangeException. You either call
>   removeObserver:forKeyPath:context: exactly once for the corresponding
>   call to addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:, or if that is not
>   feasible in your app, place the removeObserver:forKeyPath:context:
>   call inside a try/catch block to process the potential exception.

*In swift there’s no KVO API call you can make to ask, “Is X observing key path Y of object Z?” [There](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819004/5790492) is some ways to workaround it.*

**Also** [check](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/205845-cannot-remove-an-observer-because-it-is-not-registered-as-an-observer.html) the one of the reasons of the crashes when removing the observer. Here is the quote:

> "It" refers to the observer. -removeObserver:forKeyPath: raises this
>   exception if told to remove an object that isn't currently registered
>   as an observer. So what's happening is that a table view is trying to
>   unregister as an observer from one of your objects that it
>   unfortunately didn't previouly register as an observer for.
>
> The usual cause of this is that you have a property that isn't KVO-
>   compliant. Something accesses your 'foo' property and registers as an
>   observer of that property, and also as an observer of the object
>   that's the property's current value; you change the value of 'foo'
>   without letting anyone know; the observer then later decides to stop
>   observing, gets your 'foo' property, and removes itself as an observer
>   of that object. But it's no longer the same object that it registered
>   as an observer for...

Answer (score 0):

Take IBOutlet of Your UIView for Example

```
@IBOutlet var videoView:UIView!
var player:AVPlayer!

func buttonPressed()
{
    let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "your File Path")
    player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds
    videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd(_:));, name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
}

@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(_ notification: Notification?)
{
    let p = notification?.object as? AVPlayerItem
    p?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
}
```